# How do I write this lambda select method in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, linq, .net-3.5, lambda

For I've tried this:

```
Dim exampleItems As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim blah = exampleItems.Select (Function(x) New (x.Key, x.Value)).ToList 'error here
```

But I'm getting a syntax error and all the examples that I've seen are in C#.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This would be:

```
Dim blah = exampleItems.Select (Function(x) New With { .Key = x.Key, .Value = x.Value }).ToList
```

For details, see [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx).  (Depending on usage, you might also want Key or Value to be flagged with the [Key keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531349.aspx).)

That being said, `Dictionary(Of TKey, Of TValue)` already is an `IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, Of TValue)`, so you can also just do:

```
Dim blah = exampleItems.ToList
```

And you'll have a list of KeyValuePair, which has a `Key` and `Value` property already.  This really means there's no need to make the anonymous type.

Comment: +1 I was just about to post exactly the same answer, but then decided to press F5 doing so, and saw ur answer already there :)